# Release memory used for UITableView.cell.image after leaving UIViewController

Tags: image, uitableview, memory-leaks, automatic-ref-counting

I have a **UIViewController** with **UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource, NSFetchedResultsControllerDelegate** protocols. The **UIViewController** contains **UITableView** where I load some data from **Core Data.**
The loaded data include *name, subtitle* and an *image*.
They are set like:

```
cell.textLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", artist.title];
cell.detailTextLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ year", artist.year];
NSString *fileName = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"%@/%@", [[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath], artist.imageSmall];
cell.imageView.image = [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:fileName];
```

As I figured out before, **[UIImage imageNamed:]** caches the image which causes memory leaks. That's why I applied imageWithContentsOfFile method in code, where I needed to load big-size images. And it worked great. But it doesn't seem to work fine within my **UITableView**. Or I do smth wrong of cause :)

Here my images are not so heavy, they're like 20-40kb per image. It's ok even if I load 50 images per **UITableView**. It takes about 5Mb of memory to show, for example, 50 artists' photos per category. But what I noticed is that when I leave my **ViewController** and load it again via another **indexPath** (I open some other category cell and going to view the artists from that category) the memory used by app continues to increase. If I browse through 20 categories, then I get 100Mb memory usage. It doesn't look like the ARC work fine here.

So, how can I release the memory or destroy UITableView after moving back from my UIViewController?

Answer (score 2):

**2 hours later I found solution %)**

I figured out to declare UITableView as **(weak, nonatomic)** instead of **(strong, nonatomic)**.
And in **ViewDidDisappear** method I call

```
[self.tableView removeFromSuperview];
```

and memory releases successfully.